# Python-Escaping \n wrong message

Tags: python, escaping, ascii-art

I ´m trying to learn python. I want to print the following figure:

```
|°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°||
                |
                |
                |
                |
```

So, in order to achieve that, I run the following code:

```
def interface():
    IMAGEN=['''|°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°||
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |'''
            ]
    print(IMAGEN)
```

but the following image is shown in the console:

```
['|°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°||\n                               |\n                               |\n                               |\n                               |']
```

does someone know why this is printed in this way?
I ´ve even entered \n before | but the result is the same. I want to print one | below another and without \n escaping character.

thanks in advance

Comment: are you familiar with `repr()` vs `str()` ?

Comment: I 've never used repr, is that function going to help to solve ASCII issue?

Answer (score 3):

Yes because it is a list.  If you printed it out of the list (where escape codes were taken into account) it would work correctly:

```
def interface():
    IMAGEN='''|°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°||
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |'''

    print(IMAGEN)
```

Because you have printed a list it by default prints out what it actually looks as code.

Comment: it worked, thank you. and Yes, I put them in a list because my first idea was to print a list of ASCII characters, for instance:  IIIIIIII,I+++++++ #one group of characters in different index of the list and one below another.

Comment: @emilianogramajo  Super. You could do it in a list, you would just need to extract the string from the list